Is it possible to exactly compile Toffoli using H and CSWAP gates and ancilla qubits?
Question:
Given controlled-SWAP (CSWAP) and Hadamard (H) gates, is it possible to exactly compile the Toffoli (CCX) gate?
Note that I'm not looking for an encoded Toffoli gate. The answer should implement Toffoli exactly on three physical qubits. The use of ancilla qubits is allowed and, in fact, necessary (see This question for proof).

You can build a Toffoli out of five CSWAPS catalyzed by two plus states and a singlet state:

The middle CSWAP is just implementing a Z gate, so if you have an X or Z gate then the circuit can be simplified and the singlet state won't be needed.

The singlet state can be created using postselection:


Very silly terminology question perhaps - in this instance, would it fair to call the above post-selection circuit a "singlet state factory" or a "singlet state gadget"?  Is it somewhat analogous to magic state distillation?

@MarkSpinelli This would be a called a RUS (retry-until-success) gadget.
